# Can I use lubridate to get a number of instances within intervals using %within%?

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to create a visualization that shows for some predecessor/successor operations, how many employees are clocked in through a 24 hour clock.

I created a vector of instances two hours a part from each other. I converted a table of labor records (clock-in and clock-out) to a data.frame of intervals. When I use the %within% function I only get the T/F back for the first instance of my vector.

```
graph.instants <- seq( ymd("2014-05-12"), by= "2 hours", len= 120) #Make vector of instants in 2 hour intervals
ln205intervals <- data.frame(ints = interval(Frame206$LaborOn, Frame206$LaborOff)) #Make intervals with LN205 data

graph.instants %within% ln205intervals$ints
```

Is there a way to check a vector of instants against a vector of intervals?

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Frame206 is the data frame with all the *labor intervals* in it for our 206th production unit.

Comment: It is not reproducible without it. Also, the image is very nice, but is preferable that you will provide your desired output in code

Comment: David- The Frame206 dataframe has 600 records. Should I truncate it to the first 5 of each vector or so?

Comment: it's very easy to make your within function: `%within% <- function(x, interval) x >= interval[1] & x <= interval[2]
`

Answer (score 1):

for the archive as an alternative: dplyr defines a `between`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(time = seq( ymd("2015-01-01"), by= "2 hours", len= 1000))  

dat %>%  filter(between(time, ymd("2015-01-10"), ymd("2015-01-11")))
```